# LINQ - How to sum all columns of filtered dataset

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dataset that contains a stock list and i am trying to return the quantity of a user selected item.

Lets say this is the DB structure:

```
ItemName    Quantity    CheckedOut

MiniPC      4           False
MiniPC      1           False
```

To do this I am trying to use`LINQ`, however, so far I can either only return how many times the item of a specific name is listed in the database, or the first quantity field.

The first query is:

```
 var itemQtyInStock = from myRow in stockdTc.AsEnumerable()
                                         where (myRow.Field<string>("ItemName").ToUpper() == itemNameToSearch) && (myRow.Field<bool>("CheckedOut") == false)
                                         select myRow;
```

This returns: 2

the second query is:

```
var itemQtyInStockTotal = Convert.ToInt32(from myRow in stockdTc.AsEnumerable()
                                                              where (myRow.Field<string>("ItemName").ToUpper() == itemNameToSearch) && (myRow.Field<bool>("CheckedOut") == false)
                                                              select myRow.Field<string>("Quantity"));
```

This returns: 4

Both query’s are wrong as it should return: 5

How can i sum up all the quantity fields?

EDIT:

This is the answer for anyone wanting it:

```
 var itemQtyInStockTotal = stockdTc.AsEnumerable().Where(myRow => (myRow.Field<string>("ItemName").ToUpper() == itemNameToSearch) && (myRow.Field<bool>("CheckedOut") == false)).Sum(myRow => Convert.ToInt32((string)myRow["Quantity"]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
var sum = stockTc
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x=> // your filters)
    .Sum(x => (int) x["Quantity"]);
```

Comment: Perfect, took me a while to figure out how to use it, but it works exactly how i wanted. Thanks.